# Mathematical notation for number of samples of a predicted class that exceeds threshold of total number of samples

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, notation

(The title may be somewhat confusing.)

In my machine learning problem, I want to classify an *individual* based on the *samples* I have of each individual (i.e. each person has multiple samples).

Once I have made the prediction, I get the predicted class for each of the *samples*, but what I want is a global classification of the *individual* to one of the two classes.

My first idea (surely improvable) is to count the number of *samples* that have been assigned to each class, and depending on this establishing a threshold, *k*, where an *individual* will be classified as Class 1 if the number of *samples* classified as Class 1 for an *individual* exceeds that threshold.

My problem is that I don't have much knowledge of formal mathematical writing, and I would like to translate the above into mathematical notation. I have come up with the following but I don't know if it is correct.
$$
Y=1, \sum_{i=0}^{n}\hat{y_{i}}\Leftrightarrow \hat{y_{i}}=1 > k\sum_{i=0}^{n}\hat{y_{i}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is you are doing is Bootstrap classification

In general, What is Bootstrap Classification?

Suppose you are doing Logistic Regression, (meaning a binary classification problem.)

You want 100 bootstraps.
So for every bootstrap you train the model and predict the target/response.
Then you can use method of majority vote to find the final response - 0 or 1.

example - you get votes that 75 out of 100 bootstraps gives response = 1. Then you can use default threshold (which is 0.5 ratio) to classify (final prediction) it as 1 or choose different threshold to classify as 1 (maybe 0.8 ratio)

Check [this link to bagging classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html)

Default base_estimator is DecisionTree but you can give it Logistic Regression or other.

```
bag_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

# this gives the average probabilities over bootstraps
prob_x_test = bag_clf.predict_proba(x_test)

# get the binary labels based on your threshold
preds = np.where(prob_x_test>0.7,1,0)
```

Comment: It's something similar to what you say, in this case I'm actually using XGBoost, but really the problem I have is how to mathematically write the majority voting method: *an individual will be classified as class 1 if the number of samples classified as '1' is greater than a certain percentage of the total number of samples of the individual*, I wrote the formula that appears in my question, but I am not sure that it is mathematically correct and that it reflects what I am talking about.